# minitoc at beginning of every chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, minitoc

I want to have a mini table of contents for the current chapter appear just after the chapter name listing all sections of that chapter. I do this command before th begin of the document : `\usepackage{minitoc}`, and this command after the title of the chapter
`\chapter{bla}` 
`\minitoc%`
but I have this output, I don't know why
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{minitoc-hyper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \dominitoc
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \minitoc
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{One-1}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \section{One-2}
    \lipsum[5-10]
    \section{One-3}
    \lipsum[11][1-2]
    \subsection*{One-3.1}
    \lipsum[11][1-2]
    \subsection*{One-3.2}
    \lipsum[12-18]
        
    \chapter{Description}
    \minitoc
    \lipsum[30]
    \section{Two-1}
    \lipsum[31-52]
    \section{Two-2}
    \lipsum[53-62]
    
    \chapter{Objectives}
    \minitoc
    \section{Three-1}
    \lipsum[53-62]
    \section{Three-2}
    \lipsum[53-62]
\end{document}
```

You have (after two compiling) the ToC and, for each chapter:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Another output with first subsection of chapter 1 section 3 unstarred:
[image]

Comment: @CHAIMAE HAFID . I make a copy of my code from this page and I run it without problems, also with subsection 1.3.1 unstarred (see my EDIT). Perhaps you have some problem to your LaTeX configuration...

Comment: Hope the `OP` needs to update his `TeX` distribution...